# Httparty in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn how to use httparty.  I ran 'gem install httparty', first in my terminal, expecting to be able to use it in a pry session but no luck.

Next, I created a new rails app, added the gem to my gem file and ran bundle and in a pry session tried to use httparty as follows:

```
[1] pry(main)> HTTParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json")
NameError: uninitialized constant HTTParty
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'
[2] pry(main)> HTTParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json)
[2] pry(main)* httParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json)
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
httParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json)
                  ^
[2] pry(main)> httParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json")
NameError: undefined local variable or method `httParty' for main:Object
from (pry):2:in `__pry__'
[3] pry(main)> response = httParty.get("http://rubygems.org/api/v1/versions/httparty.json")
NameError: undefined local variable or method `httParty' for main:Object
from (pry):3:in `__pry__'
[4] pry(main)> response = HTTParty.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')
NameError: uninitialized constant HTTParty
from (pry):4:in `__pry__'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: you have to `require 'httparty'` in a regular `pry` session. in rails, you should be able to do `bundle exec rails console` which will load your gems and start `irb`

Answer (score 1):

require the gem, either in your pry invocation

`pry -rhttparty`

or once in pry

`require 'httparty'`

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the exact same thing right now. What I did was create a file `test_party.rb` in the rails lib directory. (Make sure to add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to your `config/application.rb`

In the new lib file create a class TestParty and `include HTTParty`

Then in rails console you can run `TestParty.whatever_you_want`

Hope that helps!